# How to marshall and unmarshall using object attribute as tag names in Java?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a class like below

```
class Element

{

   private String sElementName;

   private String sElementValue;

   private HashMap<String, String> hmAttrMap;

   private ArrayList<Element> alChildren;

}
```

Consider and object of the above class looks like this:

```
  MyElement e1 = new MyElement();

    e1.sElementName = "ElementName1";

    e1.sElementValue = "";



    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

    hm.put("att1", "value1");

    hm.put("att2", "value2");

    e1.hmAttrMap = hm;



    MyElement e2 = new MyElement();

    e2.sElementName = "ElementName2";

    e2.sElementValue = "ElementValue2";



    ArrayList<MyElement> al = new ArrayList<>();

    al.add(e2);



    e1.alChildren = al;
```

I need the below XML after marshalling the object e1

```
<ElementName1>

<ElementName2   att1=’value1’   att2=’value2’>ElementValue2</ElementName2>

</ElementName1>
```

Is it possible to do so using JAXB, I am struggling with having the name of the XML tag as the object attribute instead of the class name. Also, if there is a way to use JAXB, will it unmarshall as well?

Comment: Your sample is a bit confusing, but you can annotate `@XmlAttribute(name = "attr")` above the member var and that will generate an attribute. As for generating the contents of a map as attributes .. that's not out the box functionallity

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, but I am looking to have all the tags generated dynamically, I do not know the names while writing the code and hence cannot use @XmlAttribute(name = "attr") since the map contains the attributes and the names and values are known only at runtime.

Comment: You will have to do this yourself. Build the xml manually as you wont be able to easily rebuild your object from the xml. I would personally generate  the xml in a structured format, the map can easily translate to a named value list.

Answer (score 0):

The Element class :you have ElementName1 as Root Element and ElementName2 as child node, considering each as a separate in JaxB we can achieve this .

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ElementName1")
public class Element {

    @XmlElement(name = "ElementName2")
    Elem ele;

    public Element() {

    }

    public Elem getEle() {
        return ele;
    }

    public void setEle(Elem ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Element[  ele=" + ele + "]";
    }
}
```

Element clss2

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="ElementName2")
public class Elem {

   @XmlAttribute(name="att1")
   private int attr1;
   @XmlAttribute(name="att2")
   private int attr2;

    public Elem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }
    public void setAttr1(int attr1) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
    }
    public int getAttr2() {
        return attr2;
    }
    public void setAttr2(int attr2) {
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Elem[ attr1=" + attr1 + ",attr2="+attr2+"]";
    }

}
```

main class to give attribute values at runtime

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


public class Runningclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elem  ele2=new Elem();
        ele2.setAttr1(2);
        ele2.setAttr2(4);
        Element ele= new Element();
        ele.setEle(ele2);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Element.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            /* set this flag to true to format the output */
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            /* marshaling of java objects in xml (output to file and standard output) */
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(ele, new File("country.xml"));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(ele, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and the output: country.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ElementName1>
    <ElementName2 att1="2" att2="4"/>
</ElementName1>
```